# why "id" is the best way to find the element in selenium webdriver? not xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Why `id` is the best way to find the element in Selenium WebDriver? Not XPath?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood it's just doing a javascript page search. [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is generally a constant time lookup (O(1)) because there can only be one element per an ID on page. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2711492/379580) for a more in-depth discussion. While on some browsers it's not a hash map lookup it's still likely to be much faster then xpath (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10792780/379580)).

See this perf test https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/4 for a comparision.

Comment: thanks for the answer actually i am new in selenium webdriver and i got this question from a person and he said that xpath is slow in IE and thats why "ID" is best way to search.

Comment: could you please explain more ?