# What can xpath evaluate that querySelector can't?

Tags: javascript, xpath, css-selectors, selectors-api

I've heard ([XPath or querySelector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063306/xpath-or-queryselector)) that XPath (`evaluate`) can do everything that a CSS3 selector (`querySelector`) can and **even more**, but couldn't find what exactly "more" it can do, can you list what exactly is "more"?

Comment: Oh, XPath is much more powerful node selection mechanism. From the top of my head what XPath allows to do which CSS selector can't: 1). it has XPath Axes (parent, ancestors, and more); 2). `..` expression; 3). more convenient `position` expressions. 4). you can even use arithmetic operators, like select nodes where attribute more then ...

Comment: Is there anything you wanted to do with XPath that did not work? Or put another way: Do you have a purely theoretical interest in finding the differences between them? A specific programming question would be better suited for SO.

Comment: This is really **too broad** to answer without a specific use case.

Comment: I wanted to switch to querySelector cuz I started with xpath and was using it mostly for simply tasks (and tests said it's 2500% slower), so it's mostly theoretical to see what I'd be missing